# How to open Outlook Calendar from an UWP app with an URL

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, uwp, windows-10

I looked at this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app

and it seems that I can launch almost every Windows app, but for some reason there is not an option to launch the Calendar.. How to do it? Also, what if I want to launch a x86 program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but for some reason there is not an option to launch the Calendar.. How to do it?

You can also launch the calendar by URL. Code as follows:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("outlookcal:"));
```

The reason you don't know how to launch is that you didn't find the calendar protocol - "Url:outlookcal". Actually you may find an app protocol by open "Settings->Default Apps->Choose default apps by protocol".

[image]

> Also, what if I want to launch a x86 program?

For other win32 apps , even uwp apps that are not the default apps , they don't have `Url` protocol at default, you may need to register a protocol for the app and handle URI activation. Then you can launch it by [Launcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701476) class in the same way. More details for how to to please reference [Handle URI activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation). For example you can register `Url` for a WPF project as follows:

```
private void InstallProtocol_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var hkcr = Registry.ClassesRoot)
    {
        if (hkcr.GetSubKeyNames().Contains(SchemeName.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Looks like {0} is already installed.", SchemeName.Text));
            return;
        }

        using (var schemeKey = hkcr.CreateSubKey(SchemeName.Text))
        {
            //[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\com.aruntalkstech.wpftarget]
            //@="Url:WPF Target Protocol"
            //"URL Protocol"=""
            //"UseOriginalUrlEncoding"=dword:00000001
            schemeKey.SetValue(string.Empty, "Url: WPF Target Protocol");
            schemeKey.SetValue("URL Protocol", string.Empty);
            schemeKey.SetValue("UseOriginalUrlEncoding", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            //[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\com.aruntalkstech.wpf\shell]
            using (var shellKey = schemeKey.CreateSubKey("shell"))
            {
                //[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\com.aruntalkstech.wpf\shell\open]
                using (var openKey = shellKey.CreateSubKey("open"))
                {
                    //[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\com.aruntalkstech.wpf\shell\open\command]
                    using (var commandKey = openKey.CreateSubKey("command"))
                    {
                        //@="C:\\github\\SampleCode\\UniversalAppLaunchingWPFApp\\WPFProtocolHandler\\bin\\Debug\\WPFProtocolHandler.exe \"%1\""
                        commandKey.SetValue(string.Empty, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + " %1");
                        commandKey.Close();
                    }
                    openKey.Close();
                }
                shellKey.Close();
            }
            schemeKey.Close();
        }
        hkcr.Close();
    }

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Custom scheme {0}: installed.", SchemeName.Text));
}
```